# How to integrate pivot controll IN app bar?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone, appbar, pivotitem

Windows Phone 7.5/8 SDK

How to integrate pivot controll IN app bar?

For example "UC Browser" using this and I think it's very useful thing. [bit.ly/UmyFot](http://bit.ly/UmyFot)

This sample not work, just to present how I imagine that.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar Mode="Default" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <controls:Pivot>
            <controls:PivotItem Header="first">
                <TextBlock Text="an item"/>
                <TextBlock Text="an item two"/>
            </controls:PivotItem>
        </controls:Pivot>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: Do you mean how to show different app bar for different pivot pages?

Comment: No, I want to past pivot controll in application bar like this: bit.ly/UmyFot

Comment: But now I think this realised by Xna framework with Silverlight components, because Appbar in presented app have non-standart elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is custom realized control.

[Creating custom user control in 7 Steps](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-a-WP7-Custom-Control-in-7-Steps)

[Creating custom user control in Expression Blend for WP](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Creating_custom_user_control_in_Expression_Blend_for_Windows_Phone)

Answer (score 2):

That will have to be a custom control and cannot be achieved with the standard appbar control.